# MVC Relacionar tabla a la tabla aspnetusers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Me asignaron un proyecto donde debo crear un sistema de ventas ,pero quiero utilizar el login del Identity y relacionarlo con la tabla ventas pero no encuentro en metodo correcto

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma. 
Pongamos un ejemplo de tu tabla venta

```
public class Venta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Hora { get; set; }       

    [Display(Name = "Producto")]
    public int ProductoId { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }     
    public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }        
}
```

como se muestra en la clase el atributo ApplicationUserId representa el Id del usuario y es de tipo string puesto que Identity genera un codigo Hash y abajo haces la referencia a la tabla con

```
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser
```

de esta manera le dices a EF que ApplicationUserId es una llave foránea

ahora buscas la clase ApplicationUser que Identity genera cuando creas un proyecto asp.net en mi caso la he definido en mi contexto pero normalmente debe estar en tu carpeta Models/IdentityModels y la modificas de manera que le digas a EF que un usuario tiene una coleccion de ventas o compras desde el punto de vista del usuario

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }

}
```

después de hacer tu migración y darle un Rebuild a tu proyecto para ver que todo esta en orden agregas algo de codigo a tu controlador.

VentasController/Create

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            venta.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            db.Ventas.Add(venta); 
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

esto se hace en el controlador puesto que es transaparente al usuario.La aplicación es quien debe de encargarse de recoger su Id y anexarlo a la venta. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: gracias amigo , una consulta la clase la debo hacer codefirst ?

Comment: todo ese ejemplo es CodeFirst. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Simple.. En el identitydbcontex en onmodelcreating utilizas enlazas tus tablas y además debes declararla dbset de cada una en el contexto... no vas a poder hacer simple si tenes divididos los contextos... funciona muy bien... busca un ejemplo genial en Google que te muestra un sistema de usuarios grupos y aplicaciones en identity y vas a ver como esta echo..  es muy claro y simple... esa es tu llave... hace tus pruebas genera la migración y al revisarla te vas a dar cuenta de apoco cono ir ajustando tu código... ese es el camino y de paso aprendes bien como funciona ef